# Cartopy AzimuthalEquidistant projection: zooming into a region and coastlines

Tags: cartopy

I am trying to plot some data on an AzimuthalEquidistant projection using [cartopy](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/). However, it gives me a couple of problems. First the coastlines no longer show for this type of projection. Not sure if this is my code or a Cartopy problem. I also notice that if I use a ccrs.PlateCarree() transform in the pcolormesh command the coastlines do show but then, presumably, my data is on the wrong type of prejection?

Second I would prefer if the axis boarder was circular after plotting the data, is it possible to use set_extent or some similar function to do this?
The code below should reproduce the problems, the circle shows how I would like the boarder to look.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

clat = 55.0
clon = -8.0
lons = np.arange(clon-15,clon+16,0.5)
lats = np.arange(clat-15,clat+16,0.5)
d = np.random.rand(lons.shape[0],lats.shape[0])

trans = ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(central_latitude=clat, central_longitude=clon)

ax = plt.axes(projection=trans)
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m')

CB=ax.pcolormesh(lons-0.25, lats-0.25, d.T, 
                 cmap=plt.cm.viridis, alpha=0.5,
                 transform=trans)#ccrs.PlateCarree())

p1 = mpatches.Circle((clon,clat), radius=15, color='k', lw=5, fill=False,
                     transform=trans)
ax.add_patch(p1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data you are plotting is in latitude/longitude coordinates then the correct value for the `transform` keyword is indeed `ccrs.PlateCarree()`. This is common gotcha for new users. The `transform` argument tells cartopy what coordinates your data are in, and is completely independent of the `projection` you want to plot onto.

To make the plot circular you'll need to set the boundary yourself. The Cartopy documentation have a couple of examples of this: http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/always_circular_stereo.html and http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/star_shaped_boundary.html.